# FBSDKLoginManager return "You have already authorized foobar" and not redirect to my view

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm using Facebook SDK 4.+ and added login flow to my application. After I sign in authroized the app, the web view won't go away. I can only tap on done which will cancel the auth flow instead of finish it.

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
[login
 logInWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile", @"email"]
 fromViewController:self
 handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
     if (error) {
         NSLog(@"Process error");
     } else if (result.isCancelled) {
         NSLog(@"Cancelled");
     } else {
         //this never get executed.
         [self firebaseSignInWithFBToken:[result token].tokenString];
     }
 }];
```

Any suggestions?

And for authorized application, when I set `currentAccessToken` to `nil` and re-authorize,

[image].

Upon click ok, the webview went blank and won't dismiss itself to go back to my own view.

Comment: Make sure you have all the values in your info.plist required to configure Facebook account, make sure you set the required functions in app delegate including the open url function where actually the problem may reside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be the main reason this(White screen in simulator) is happening because the openURL method in appDelegate is not set properly.

I've had this problem before, solved this by using this piece of code.
This code is in swift.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {

    var shouldOpen :Bool = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application,openURL: url,sourceApplication: sourceApplication,annotation: annotation)

    shouldOpen = shouldOpen ? shouldOpen : GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,
                                                                                sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
                                                                                annotation: annotation)
    return shouldOpen

}

/// This is necessary for ios9 and plus
func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool {
    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        var shouldOpen :Bool = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(
            app,
            openURL: url,
            sourceApplication: options["UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey"] as! String,
            annotation: nil)

        shouldOpen = shouldOpen ? shouldOpen : GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] as! String?,
                                                                                    annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey])

        return shouldOpen
    }
    return true
}
```

If you are not using Gmail login remove the GIDsign code and simply return the facebook callback.